# SRS: geographic or cartesian?

Tags: proj

Let's have a list of SRS with proj4 definitions (e.g. spatial_ref_sys table). Is there a way to determine whether given SRS is geographic (lon,lat) or cartesian (x,y)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a look at the proj4text string, and whether or not it has "`+units=x`" (usually m for metres) in there.

@dariapra's answer implies that all cartesian co-ordinate systems are projected using Universal Transverse Mercator, which isn't the case at all.

Answer (score -2):

If geographic, you will see that *+proj=longlat*; for instance, for SRS with EPSG code 4326:

> **+proj=longlat** +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs

If cartesian, you will see that *+proj=utm*, which stands for [Universal Transverse Mercator coordinate system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system), which is cartesian; for instance, for SRS with EPSG code 23029:

> **+proj=utm** +zone=29 +ellps=intl +units=m +no_defs

Comment: Not if the data is in a non-utm projection

Comment: There is much more than "longlat" and "utm", e.g. tmerc, somerc, omerc, lcc, krovak, cass, sterea, aea, laea, stere, cea. Is "longlat" geographic SRS and the rest is cartesian?